# regex replace whole string with http with blank

Tags: python, regex

lets say I have a string

```
string = "Today is going well the dog jumped over the fence. The fence was 
my neighbors asdkhttps://www.urldefence.org/ult/sdfo/90nf3f/lknfksjdn? 
>>>09sdkfjnkbIAS(F89kjfs and here are some more words before another link 
lkm.http//www.someothersite.com/kasd09/3oif/3fo3/3/nffiosuf??? 
DF*SDF***8skdjnf and some more words in the end."
```

I want to just replace the long strings that contain the http link, defined by space before the text, and space after, with http being somewhere in the middle.

I've been trying..

```
re.sub('\bhttps?\b', '', string)
re.sub('https?.*?', '', string)
re.sub('https?.*?([\s+])', '', string)
```

having trouble connecting the dots.

Comment: How do you define when the link ends?

Comment: apologies, space at the beginning and space at the end.

Comment: So `re.sub(r'https?://\S*', '', string)`?

Comment: Yup, that's the one. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not much good in regex but I tried following regex and it match the string you want with space. So you can try this if work.

```
http.*?([\s])
```

Comment: this is close to what I want. what about everything before http as well?

Comment: It will exclude the content before http

Comment: yeah I figured out adding it anyways. but this got me close. thanks